# Let f(x, y, z) = $xe^{y+z^ 2}$, where $z = z(x, y)$ is itself implicitly a function of x and y given by $z + e^z = x + 2y$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let f(x, y, z) = $xe^{y+z^
2}$, where $z = z(x, y)$ is itself implicitly a function of x and y given by
$z + e^z = x + 2y$.

Find ∂f/∂$\vec{u}$ at (1, 0), where $\vec{u} = 2\vec{i}+\vec{j}$

So I guess we can think of f as a function of just x and y, but I am having trouble solving this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$g(x,y)=f(x,y,z(x,y))$$
Then what you want is the directional derivative of $g$ at $(1,0)$. It suffices to obtain the gradient first, then take inner product of the gradient with $\vec{u}/ |\vec{u}|$. To calculate the gradient, note that
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
You know how to calculate partial derivatives of $f$, and you need implicit function theorem to calculate $\partial z / \partial x$.
The $\partial f/ \partial y$ part can be computed similarly.

Calculation of $\partial z / \partial x$:
$$z+e^z=x+2y$$
Take partial derivative with respect to $x$, and view $z$ as a function of $x,y$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+e^z \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 1$$
Thus
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{1+e^z}$$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. How would I use the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @JackHarold I've included it in my answer.

Comment: Okay. So what would be the equation for the directional derivative of g?

Comment: How would I use the gradient to solve for the directional derivative?

Comment: @JackHarold Like I said, take the inner product of the gradient with the unit vector along that direction.